# converting varchar to integer

Tags: sql, varchar

I am trying to count the number of records in the Face column that is between 0 and 25000.  The dataset has Face as a char(20) so I needed to convert it to an integer before making any boolean expression.  Here's my code below:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tablename
WHERE cast(face AS integer) > 0 and cast(face AS integer) <=25000;
```

I get an error, saying

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.0' to data type int.

Face column contains null values and records like '0.0' and '0.0000'

I've looked online and haven't found anything useful on how to convert varchar to integer.  Help anyone?

Comment: `I've looked online and haven't found anything useful on how to convert varchar to integer.` Nope...

Comment: Why, why, why are you storing integers in a char(20) column? Also, a search turned up nothing? Really? I guess you mean after you inspected [all 508,000 results from this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+varchar+to+int+sql+server)? Or even more close to home, [the 1,043 results found right here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+varchar+to+int+sql-server)?

Comment: @reto I would have to agree and suggest that the OP look a little harder.

Comment: The performance on this query is gonna suck as well, as it'll have to go through every row in the table to cast it to a number.  You seriously need to re-consider the data type for this column so you can take advantage of indexes.

Comment: You might not find anything on AOL's proprietary search thing but I bet if you went to the big internet, you could find something

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+varchar+to+int&aq=0&oq=convert+varchar+to+i&aqs=chrome.0.0j57j5j0j60l2.8420j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

If your column has decimal points in it, your mistake is trying to interpret it as an integer:

```
select count(*)
from tablename
where cast(face AS float) > 0.0 and cast(face AS float) <= 25000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `Face` always guaranteed to be numeric?  Hopefully so or any approach won't work very well for you.

Since you have decimal values, your best bet is to cast it as a `float` and then do your comparison:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tablename
WHERE cast(face AS float)> 0 and cast(face AS float) <=25000;
```